# Using Lower Bound With Vector of Object Pointers

Tags: c++, vector, lower-bound

I have this data structure:

```
class Person {
 public:
  string email, name, surname
};

class Bus {
  vector<Person *> sortedbyemail;
  vector<Person *> sortedbyname;
};
```

now I want to add the pointers to the right position, so I dont have to sort later. As this led me to lower_bound() I finished with the following, not even compilable code in my Add() method:

```
bool Add(string name, string surname, string email) {
  Person *p = new Person(name, surname, email);
  auto it_l = lower_bound(
      sortedbyemail.begin(), sortedbyemail.end(), email,
      [](Person *x, Person *y) { return ((x->email) < (y->email)); });
}
```

now, the compiler throws an error at me: "expected expression" with an arrow pointing to [] in the compare method. Also, this doesn't fit into my OOP scheme, as I needed to allow for email to be public.

Comment: Please also make a habit of including full error messages and an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The second parameter to the comparator is the value that `std::lower_bound` is searching for, its third parameter. You are passing a `std::string`, hence the second parameter to the lambda must be a `std::string`.

Comment: Your comparison function can't compare `string` to `Person*`.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering, third parameter of lower_bound() is passed as an argument for the Comparator operator in this case (It usually is a function). If you want to compare using two object pointers like I do, you need to use something similar to this:

```
struct PersonMailComparator{
  bool operator()( const Person * left, const Person * right )const 
  {
    //try for yourself to figure out what you need here, for me it is:
    return left->email.compare(right->email) < 0;
  }
};
```

and when adding new person pointer to your vector

```
Person * p = new Person ( name, surname, email );
auto it_l = lower_bound( sortedbyemail.begin(), sortedbyemail.end(),
                         p, PersonMailComparator() );
```

Comment: You can use a lambda instead of a functor. Also,  `compare()` returns an `int`, not a `bool` like `lower_bound()` is expecting the predicate to return. Try this instead: `auto it_l = lower_bound( sortedbyemail.begin(), sortedbyemail.end(), p, [](Person * left, Person * right){ return left->email < right->email; } );`